# DataBase for documents

Tags: database, document

I am beginning a new project and want to choose a db.
I don't have a fixed language yet but was thinking to go with Java 15 and spring.
The issue I have is that, this time, I will manage lots of documents (mainly scans or pictures).
I don't know which db does it best, or if I need to add a particular API.

What is the best database choice to manage docs ?
Do I need to consider specifics API to help ?

Thank you

Comment: I'd store the files in a cloud storage (S3 or similar). Then store the links in a db.

Comment: I see the idea, but it's for a profesisonnal project. I will need more than 5Go, i'm already at 14

Comment: What do you mean, you need more than 5Go? S3 can hold many terabytes.

Comment: True, but when I looked it up, it said the free trial was only up to 5go

Comment: Your DB isn't free either.

Comment: I'm confused, I mean, I can have space if i put it on a physical server (which I have) and there are free db solutions (mysql or postgresql for instance)